# Show $\lim{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+3}}+...\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}}=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Show that
$$\lim{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+3}}+...\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}}=\infty$$.

not allowed to use series test and any result/test of series. Only things allowed are use of first principles $\epsilon $ $\delta$ definition , cauchy's convergence etc.

I tried to use $Cauchy's$ $ Criterion$ for convergence of sequences since $S_{n+1}-S_{n}$ comes out nicely . But it doesn't leads to result. Hints are appreciated .

Have a good day !

Comment: That are $n$ terms, each of which is $\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}$. So ...

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi In general $1/\sqrt{n+1}$ is the largest term in the sum, not the smallest.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: can we show by $\epsilon \delta$ / cauchy's ?

Comment: Since the expression is $\gt \sqrt{n/2}\to \infty$, the $\epsilon,\delta$ approach doesn't make sense.  It is used when the proposed limit is finite.

Answer (score 0):

We know that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}} \geq \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}} $$
And
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{2n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2}} = \infty $$

So

$$\therefore \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}} = \infty$$

Comment: This is not the right way to justify divergence. A sequence $\{a_n\}$ diverges to $+\infty$ means, for any given $M>0$, there is $N=N(M)\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|a_n|>M$.